# mySQL query using join

Tags: mysql, date, join

I have 2 tables - 'cityname' and 'citymoisture'.

```
'cityname' has 2 columns:  
-city_ID <- integer and primary key that increments automatically  
-city_full_name <- character name i.e. boston, toronto, new york city etc...  

'citymoisture' has 7 columns:  
-city_ID <- tied to the city_ID field via a Foreign Key  
-date  
-time  
-open  
-high  
-low  
-close
```

What I want to do is -

Query for any of open, high, low and close in the moisture table by specifying the name of the city and date range.

The following query works:

```
USE moisturedb  
SELECT citymoisture.date, citymoisture.time, citymoisture.close  
FROM citymoisture  
WHERE (citymoisture.date BETWEEN '2011/03/09' AND '2011/03/14') AND citymoisture.city_id=5;
```

But this only references the 'citymoisture' table. I have a front end application that allows users to select the city name so in a sense I want to run a joined query that drops the results based on the city_full_name column in the cityname table.

I've tinkered around with a few join queries without success. I have also spent the last several hours searching through join query examples without any success.

I greatly appreciate your help.

As a follow-up to Nikhil's request here is a sample output of the query suggested.

```
| 2011-03-10   | 03:38:00     | 0.918 |
| 2011-03-10   | 03:39:00     | 0.897 |
| 2011-03-10   | 03:40:00     | 0.917 |
| 2011-03-10   | 03:41:00     | 0.915 |
| 2011-03-10   | 03:42:00     | 0.914 |
| 2011-03-10   | 03:43:00     | 0.924 |
| 2011-03-10   | 03:44:00     | 0.922 |
| 2011-03-10   | 03:45:00     | 0.922 |
| 2011-03-10   | 03:46:00     | 0.923 |
| 2011-03-10   | 03:47:00     | 0.935 |
| 2011-03-10   | 03:48:00     | 0.953 |
| 2011-03-10   | 03:49:00     | 0.927 |  
| 2011-03-10   | 03:50:00     | 0.962 |  
| 2011-03-10   | 03:51:00     | 0.914 |  
| 2011-03-10   | 03:52:00     | 0.935 |  
+--------------+--------------+-------+  
14770 rows in set (2 min 28.80 sec)
```

Where the 3rd column is the moisture data. The values for each city in the query are knitted together in the sense that they are stacked one after the other. I would very much like the following output where the moisture data for each city appear in separate columns:

```
2011-03-10  03:49:00  0.935  0.935  0.935  .....  
2011-03-10  03:50:00  0.935  0.935  0.935  .....  
2011-03-10  03:51:00  0.935  0.935  0.935  .....  
2011-03-10  03:52:00  0.935  0.935  0.935  .....  
2011-03-10  03:53:00  0.935  0.935  0.935  .....  
2011-03-10  03:54:00  0.935  0.935  0.935  .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
USE moisturedb  
SELECT citymoisture.date, citymoisture.time, citymoisture.close  
FROM citymoisture INNER JOIN cityname ON cityname.city_ID=citymoisture.city_ID
WHERE (citymoisture.date BETWEEN '2011/03/09' AND '2011/03/14') AND cityname.city_full_name='boston'
```

Comment: Hi Mahin - I had another question for you. Is it possible to pull the data for multiple city names? i.e. cityname.city_full_name='boston, toronto, atlanta, orlando' etc...??

Comment: you can use some thing like this; `WHERE (citymoisture.date BETWEEN '2011/03/09' AND '2011/03/14') GROUP BY cityname.city_full_name` This will group the results based on city name. If you really want only selected cities try using `OR` for eg: `WHERE (citymoisture.date BETWEEN '2011/03/09' AND '2011/03/14') AND (cityname.city_full_name='Boston' OR cityname.city_full_name='NY')`. Else you can try using [pattern matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: oops... I forgot `IN` function as @nikhil500 mentioned you can use that as well  :)

Comment: Thank you Mahin - the only thing is that the results for 'citymoisture.close' are knitted together. I was hoping to get mySQL to treat each city as its own column in the query output. Hmmm...

Comment: "to treat each city as its own column in the query output" this would be a pivot or crosstab query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT citymoisture.date, citymoisture.time, citymoisture.close 
FROM citymoisture LEFT JOIN cityname USING (city_ID)
WHERE (citymoisture.date BETWEEN '2011/03/09' AND '2011/03/14')
AND citymoisture.city_full_name='boston';
```

However, I think the query that you have posted in your question is the one that should be used. You must be having a front-end with a drop-down for the user to select the city. That drop-down can be populated using `cityname` such that the `city_ID` is sent back to the server when the user selects a city. You can then use the `city_ID` in the original query that you have posted. For reference, check the `value` attribute of the `option` tag [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp).

Comment: Hi nikhil500. Thanks for the code and feedback. Its a bit more complicated so the city name is what I need. That being said - how do I produce a result that pulls the citymoisture.date, citymoisture.time, and close data for a list of city names? Can I add a list of names on citymoisture.city_full_name='boston, toronto, atlanta, orlando'???

Comment: SELECT citymoisture.date, citymoisture.time, citymoisture.close 
FROM citymoisture LEFT JOIN cityname USING (city_ID)
WHERE (citymoisture.date BETWEEN '2011/03/09' AND '2011/03/14')
AND citymoisture.city_full_name IN ('boston', 'toronto', 'atlanta', 'orlando')

Comment: Thank you Nikhil - the only thing is that the results for 'citymoisture.close' are knitted together. I was hoping to get mySQL to treat each city as its own column in the query output. Hmmm

Comment: Could you post an example output that you are getting with the query above and the output that you actually expect?

Comment: Hi Nikhil... I just updated my original post with a sample output and a desired output. I hope that helps. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that is possible - the number of columns in the result is not fixed and I think MySQL does not support such queries.